# Cannot figure out a second order lineary differential equation with initial values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I got the following question:

Solve the following initial value problem:
$y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = 1$, $$y'' + 10y' + 25y = 0$$

So I started with getting the general solution:
$$
y(x) = C_1e^{-5x} + xC_2e^{-5x}
$$
And then calculating the derative while i am at it:
$$
y'(x) = -5C_1e^{-5x} -5C_2xe^{-5x}
$$
After filling in the conditions, the solution should be:
$y = xe^{-5x}$. And that is where I get stuck: I do not get that answer.

First i fill in condition y(0) = 0
$$
0 = C_1*1 + 0 => C_1 = 0
$$
And then y'(0) = 1:
$$
1 = -5C_1*1 + 0 => C_1 = -1/5
$$
Which is, obviously incorrect. Where did I make the mistake? How do I solve this?

Comment: Try differentiating again. Also `\implies` yields $\implies$.

Comment: You forgot to use the product rule when differentiating $y$

Comment: The solution of the ODE is not correct for $y'' + 10y' + 25 = 0$. Could it be  $y'' + 10y' + 25 y= 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:
$$
y'(x) = -5C_1e^{-5x} -5C_2xe^{-5x} \color{red}{+C_2 e^{-5x}}
$$
by the product rule.

Comment: Indeed, the last term should be C2e^(-5x). But you got the fault, so still an upvote.

Comment: How embarassing! I fixed it.